# Ruby using a date as key in a hash from MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, date, hash

I have a hash which is the result of a `.map` method on a MySQL2::Result object which looks like this:

`{#<Date: 2018-01-02 ((2458121j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>"OL,BD,DM,WW,DG"}
{#<Date: 2018-01-03 ((2458122j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>"KP,LW"}
{#<Date: 2018-01-04 ((2458123j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>"LW,WW,FS,DG"}
{#<Date: 2018-01-05 ((2458124j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>"OL,KP,BD,SB,LW,DM,AS,WW,FS,DG"}
{#<Date: 2018-01-06 ((2458125j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>"OL,KP,BD,SB,LW,DM,AS,WW,FS,DG"}`

I would like to pull the values (the two letter items) from the hash, by referencing with the key.

I have tried

```
puts hash_name["2018-01-06"]
puts hash_name['2018-01-06']
puts hash_name[Date.new(2018,1,6)]
puts hash_name["<Date: 2018-01-06 ((2458125j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>"]
puts hash_name["#<Date: 2018-01-06 ((2458125j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>"]
```

All return nothing or an error.

The hash is created by doing the following:

```
hash_name = @available_items.map do
|h| {h["tdate"] => h["items"] }
end
```

Is there something I can do during the creation of the hash, or now, to be able to easily pull the value out using e.g. can I convert it to some other date format like ISO format?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close here, but you're generating an array of hashes, not a singular hash:

```
hash_name = @available_items.map do |i|
  [ i["tdate"], i["items"] ]
end.to_h
```

This creates an array of key/value pair arrays, then converts them to a hash with the [`.to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) method.

You can also use [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) if your input data can be grouped neatly, like:

```
hash_name = @available_items.group_by do |i|
  i['tdate']
end
```

Where that approach might be good enough if can deal with the output format. It's keyed by date.

Note that using symbol keys like `:tdate` and `:items` is usually preferable to string keys. It's worth trying to steer towards that in most cases where there'd otherwise be rampant repetition of those strings.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Can you please explain further about symbol keys? I understand the general concept of symbols, but am not sure how that would work in this situration.  Are you suggesting that each `tdate` (e.g. "2018-01-06") should become `:2018-01-06` for example.

Comment: I'm not suggesting the dates themselves become symbols, that'd be messy, but that the key the date is stored under is, or `:tdate` instead of `'tdate'`. Ruby's 1.9+ hash declaration style, syntactically like JavaScript, uses this by default: `{ tdate: '2018-01-06' }` is equivalent to `{ :tdate => '2018-01-06' }`.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that `Enumerable#map` doesn't do what you think it does. This:

```
hash_name = @available_items.map do
|h| {h["tdate"] => h["items"] }
end
```

will give you an *array* of single entry hashes, the individual hashes will map Dates to strings but the result looks like:

```
[
  { date1 => string1 },
  { date2 => string2 },
  ...
]
```

rather than:

```
{
  date1 => string1,
  date2 => string2,
  ...
}
```

as you're expecting. Switching to `#each_with_object` should take care of your problem:

```
hash_name = @available_items.each_with_object({}) do |row, h|
  h[row['tdate']] = row['items']
end
```

Comment: @tadman Sometimes, but sometimes I prefer the heresy of `each_with_object` :)

Comment: Technically it creates less garbage, but strangely it doesn't always perform better. Ruby is a strange thing internally.

Answer (score 0):

In the hopes that this may help others to do a similar thing, here is what I ended up doing.

I have a MySQL2::Result object as shown above, on which I run:

```
@available_hash = @available_items.map do |row|
[ row["tdate"], row["available"] ]
end.to_h
```

Having previously declared a `start_date` and an `end_date` I then select an available item from the list, at random to fill a new hash using the dates as keys:

```
$final_hash = Hash.new("")
for date in (start_date..end_date)
@available_today = @available_hash[date].to_s.split(",")
$final_hash[date] = random_item(@available_today)
date +=1;
end
```

Whilst I am sure there is probably a more elegant way of doing this, I am delighted that you have helped me to get this to work!

Answer (score -1):

Obviously hash map is not suitable for a date as the key, hash map is more suitable for key as id, tag, etc. It should be a unique key.

Please provide more information about what you need to do with this hash map, for sure you can have some more clever data structure.

If you have an array with two keys (tdate, items) and you want to lookup for the date just use select:

```
result = available_items.select { |elem| elem['tdate'] === Date.new(2001,2,3) }
```

reference for '===' operator in Date class
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D